# google apps script: create dynamic htmlbody

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm actually stuck with a problem with Google Apps Script and I hope anyone might be able to help me.

I'm currently working on a script which sends out a weekly infomail containing a pdf file and several images (number of images not fixed). Additionally the images should be displayed in the E-Mail (working with the htmlBody option).

Now my problem is as follows: The number of the images I want to send with the email is not fixed so at the moment I have to hardcode the htmlBody which is kind of ugly.

```
htmlBody = "<img src='cid:diagramm1'/><img src='cid:diagramm2'/><img src='cid:diagramm3'/>

     GmailApp.sendEmail(test@mailinator.com,
                        subject ,
                        recipient[0],message,
                                {htmlBody: htmlBody,
                                 inlineImages:{
                                       diagram1:attach[1], 
                                       diagram2:attach[2],
                                       diagram3:attach[3],
                                 },
                                 attachments:attach[0]});
  });

}

//not used atm
function buildHtmlBody(){

  for(i=0;i<DIAGRAM_NAMES.length;i++){

    htmlBody += "<img src='cid:" + DIAGRAM_NAMES[i] + "'/>";

  }
```

I think the problem is easy to spot. In Codeline #7 I list all inline images diagram1-3 by hand. I tried using variables but it doesn't work.

Actually I have an array where I store the information about each diagram (so I know how many of them I have).

Is there any possiblity to make this nicer? I would like to make the code adjustable to a variable number of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
htmlBody = "<img src='cid:diagramm1'/><img src='cid:diagramm2'/><img src='cid:diagramm3'/>

     var inlineImages  = {}; 
     for (var i = 1; i <= DIAGRAM_NAMES.length ; i++){
        inlineImages["diagram" + i.toString()] = attach[i]; 
     }
     GmailApp.sendEmail(test@mailinator.com,
                        subject ,
                        recipient[0],message,
                                {htmlBody: htmlBody,
                                 inlineImages:inlineImages,
                                 attachments:attach[0]});
  });

}

//not used atm
function buildHtmlBody(){

  for(i=0;i<DIAGRAM_NAMES.length;i++){

    htmlBody += "<img src='cid:" + DIAGRAM_NAMES[i] + "'/>";

 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this fast answer!

That seems to be a way but I think there is still a mistake in it. In inlineImages the assignment DIAGRAM_NAMES[i]:DIAGRAM_NAMES[i] is missing.

Comment: Yes I'm getting the following error: ReferenceError:

"diagram" is undefined

Comment: Oh Thank you very much! That's it. It's working very well.

One more question, is inlineImages kind of a keyToValue list?

Comment: inlineImages takes a JavaScript object as an argument. Even in the code I provided, inlineImages is a Javascript object